# Result as rows with one in each row

Tags: teradata

I have a query that returns a numeric value either negative or positive. Need to change to an absolute value and then display the value as a 1 in each row to the total returned eg if result is 5 then result would be :

```
Value
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
```

where the first column is the row and the second column is the result.

If -3:

```
Value
1   1
2   1
3   1
```

The tables as examples don't display as tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sys_calendar.calendar, but you might use any table with a sequence of numbers in it:

```
select 1
from sys_calendar.calendar
where day_of_calendar between 1 and abs(your query returning a single row/value)
```

This will work up to 73,414, which is the row count of sys_calendar.calendar

Since TD13.10 there's also EXPAND ON, which only works on periods, but up to 3,652,058 (number of days between 0001-01-01 and 9999-12-31:

```
select 1
from (your query returning a single row/value) AS dt
expand on period(date '0001-01-01', date '0001-01-01' + abs(cnt)) as newpd
```

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth, I am able to use the first query with the result cast as an integer, the second on I am unable to get to use. Tried casting my query as a date but still only getting one row as the result. Even if a number is entered as my result.

Comment: #2 works for me. The `cnt` is the integer value returned by your query.